# not getting IPN response back

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, paypal-ipn

After successful payment, it is redirecting me at success URL but I am not getting response from IPN.

Below is the `notifypage.aspx.cs` page code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //Post back to either sandbox or live
    string strSandbox = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
    // string strLive = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strSandbox);

    //Set values for the request back
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    byte[] param = Request.BinaryRead(HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentLength);
    string strRequest = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(param);
    strRequest += "&cmd=_notify-validate";
    req.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;

    //for proxy
    //WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(new Uri("http://url:port#80"));
    //req.Proxy = proxy;

    //Send the request to PayPal and get the response
    StreamWriter streamOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
    streamOut.Write(strRequest);
    streamOut.Close();
    StreamReader streamIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
    string strResponse = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
    streamIn.Close();


    if (strResponse == "VERIFIED")
    {

        File.WriteAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~") + @"\Notify.txt", "Student1111" + Environment.NewLine + "----------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
    }
    else if (strResponse == "INVALID")
    {
        File.WriteAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~") + @"\Notify.txt", "Problem with payment : " + Environment.NewLine + "----------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
    }
    else
    {
        File.WriteAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~") + @"\Notify.txt", "not any" + Environment.NewLine + "----------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

So please help me how could I get back the IPN response?

Comment: Have enabled IPN in the merchant's account and added the IPN URL?

Answer (score 0):

You should test working of your `IPN Listner` here

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNTesting/

Comment: @G Ravinder I have tried in ipn simulator also but there it is giving me this error : "We could not send an IPN due to an HTTP error: 500: Internal Server Error"

Comment: Please check your IPN listner code. It is generating an Exception
Possible reasons:
You may be reading the variable that does not exists in the request

Please use Try{}Catch{} and save or send mail to self, the details of the exception in ipn listner to test the error

Answer (score -1):

Paypal `IPN` response calls only server domains, if you trying it on local host it will not call your notify url page.

Comment: @JayeshTanna I made edit of answer only (text was in code format).

Comment: yeah but if you are testing from local host  it will not work, you can test it after uploading on server

Comment: @RohitSharma hi,I have already uploaded it on server but still it is not responding me.